# AngularJS and Microsoft Edge

Tags: angularjs, microsoft-edge

I'm loading minified version of AngularJS file as follow

`<script src="js/lib/angularjs/angular.min.js"></script>`

but when load my app in the Edge browser it throws an error that angular.js 404 Not Found but the app works fine.

How and why Edge needs to load not minified version of angular.js?

Screenshot from Developer Tool:

[image]

Comment: Is it saying that `angular.js` is not found, or `angular.min.js` is not found?

Comment: @ExplosionPills Correct. OP has attached screenshot with that error. I do not user not minified version of angular.js anywhere in my code

Comment: do you have a map specified in the minified version?

maybe it's trying to load the non-minified to show it to you in dev tools

Comment: @GradientByte Yes, I have a map for the minified version.

Comment: @JackTheKnife Have you solved that issue?